# Spring ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource configuration

Tags: spring, configuration

I develop a simple Spring application which is my university task. There are 3 configuration files: web.xml, core-context.xml, dispatcher-servlet.xml and 1 file with default properties which is called messages.properties and is located in /WEB-INF/ folder.

In my application I have the following configuration of ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource and it works fine:

**core-context.xml**

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
  <property name="basenames" value="/WEB-INF/messages" />
  <property name="useCodeAsDefaultMessage" value="true" />
</bean>
```

**web.xml**

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>classpath*:core-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

But it turned out that my task instruction says that I should configure ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource bean in dispatcher-servlet.xml. The problem is that whenever I remove the above configuration from core-context.xml and put it in dispatcher-servlet.xml my locals are no longer displayed.

Could you explain to me why the problem occurs?
What is a difference between putting bean configuration inside core-context.xml and dispatcher-servlet.xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not posted your dispatcher-servlet.xml but I believe it is not being initialized by the spring container because it is not declared anywhere. If you must have another file called dispatcher-servlet.xml as you specify then you can just import it in your core-context.xml. This should solve your problem.